# What's RedHat integrity test?

Tags: virtualbox, redhat-enterprise-linux, data-integrity

The binary DVD `*.iso`s for installing the Red Hat OS, which I downloaded from https://access.redhat.com/downloads/, I checked, has the same SHA-256 reported in the webpage.  But when I boot the computer from that DVD (actually I'm using Virtual Box) and ask the boot loader to test the installation media, it says it's not good.  I can't find anything about what that ["integrity test"](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-installation-source-x86) is about so I don't even know where to look in trying to install this.  I'm trying to install Red Hat 8.2 on Virtual Box.  Anybody knows what I should do?

Edit:
I always get an error during installation.  I give it 4GB RAM, 10GB fixed-sized Virtual Box virtual disk, standard partitioning, tried a bunch of software configurations included the minimal, and still it always stops in the middle with some error.

Edit 2: When I tried again to give you the screenshot, the installation media passed the test, even twice in a row.  I didn't change anything myself.  Was it my memory utilization in the host?  That's the only thing I can think of.  But now I installed it twice and I don't have a screenshot with the error for you.  But I swear it was not passing before so I'm still listening for ideas.

Comment: You will want to provide a screenshot.  Everything on that website is behind a paywall.

Comment: You just need a RedHat free developer account to see that website.  Anyways it just has the SHA-256 next to the download links.

Comment: Please add a screenshot (or text copy) of the full error.

Comment: If you have access to a Windows computer, you can download it there and check with digestIT 2004.  That is still good hash check software.

Comment: According to your addition, the answer would be "try it again"?

Comment: No because I can't guarantee it's going to work if you try again.  I tried like 10 times before posting the question, and now it's working every time, even different configurations.

Comment: The ONLY thing that makes RedHat ok is that you have support for it.  What has RedHat support told you?